# Replaced burnt infinite switch still doesn't generate heat

Tags: electrical, stove

We have a Kenmore range with a non-functioning surface element. Based on an earlier experience, I knew that the issue must be due to a burnt infinite switch. After opening the back of the stove and removing the corresponding switch (see attached picture), it was confirmed that the switch was burnt. To replace that, I purchased [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0856PP512) product, which seems to have all specifications matching the broken switch. After installation, though, the surface element still doesn't heat. I am now wondering what else could be the reason for this not to function. Any thoughts or recommendations are highly appreciated.

[image: Burnt infinite switch]

Comment: why wouldn't you consider the element be one of possible failures?

Comment: It could be, though, the switch is burnt so I assumed it could be the only root cause. Haven't dared to open the surface and test out or play with the element, though.

Comment: You need to get a basic multi meter to test the element . A simple ohm meter will show if the element is open , much cheaper than throwing parts at it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily a bad switch. That type of switch is constantly opening and closing contacts carrying the full load current of the surface heating element, and in normal operation produces arcing and black marks in the area near to the contacts.